# How to specify username and password in the DSN?

Tags: php, pdo, php-7.4

The official documentation page for [PDO DSN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) does not list out username or password yet. What is the correct name for these key-value pairs?

Comment: What's wrong with specifying them as separate arguments as shown in the documentation you've linked?

Comment: Why is this tagged as "php-7.4"? Is there a particular reason for it?

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong, other than the fact that if there is a problem they will be present in the call stack. If you include everything in the DSN then you can avoid that problem, which is why I believe they have just added that possibility.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is only possible in PHP 7.4 as far as I know.

Comment: [Probably relevant.](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a7881df281f74e13cf360fd3624ef849ce747e33#diff-7748eb3bfdd3bf962553f6f9f2723c45R253)

Comment: @Jeto Perfect. This is what I was looking for. So it is `user` instead of `username`, correct?

Comment: @Dharman It doesn't specify a version probably because it wasn't/isn't version specific. Per https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php - it shows that the driver/library has been made available since version 5.x.x

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner See [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78033). This was implemented only in PHP 7.4.0

Comment: @Dharman Looks like it. [This is the original pull request for reference.](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2684)

Comment: @Dharman ah ok, thanks for that. I stand corrected :) Maybe you guys might want to post an answer, or as a community wiki?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Let's see what they post ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the documentation hasn't been updated yet, but [this is the related change](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.4/UPGRADING#L321) from PHP's source repository, stating how it should be used:

> - PDO: The username and password can now be specified as part of the PDO DSN for
>   the mysql, mssql, sybase, dblib, firebird and oci drivers. Previously this
>   was only supported by the pgsql driver. If a username/password is specified
>   both in the constructor and the DSN, the constructor takes precedence.
>
>   ```
>     new PDO("mysql:host=xxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx");
>   ```

And here's the [associated pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2684).