# mysqli_connect using credentials as a single variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to my localhost database with PHP using credentials as a single variable (just for simplicity and easy of maintenance) but I can't get it to work.

The following works fine:

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','news_db');
```

But the following does not:

```
$con_details="'localhost', 'root', '','news_db'";
$con=mysqli_connect($con_details);
```

I get an error of "No such Host Known"

Comment: That would all pass as one parameter to `mysqli_connect`, so it is all the `host` value. Why not just do it the standard way? You should only be doing that once.

Comment: If you want to use a single variable, and array would be fine..

Comment: Why not switch to PDO? You can do that with PDO and it is easier to use.

Comment: @Dharman Username and password can't be passed as one variable to PDO..or can they?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, they can. See [How to specify username and password in the DSN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59448952/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman Oh, thanks. Never seen that before. (Ah, it is a new feature)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mysqli_connect` function has the following signature:

```php
mysqli_connect ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") 
                [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") 
                [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") 
                [, string $dbname = "" 
                [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") 
                [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") 
          ]]]]]] ) : mysqli
```

That is, it takes six (optional) arguments, and any missing arguments are taken from the PHP ini file. There's no way you can concatenate host, username, password and database name into a single string, because that would be just one argument which `mysqli_connect` would understand as the hostname.

If you must store your credentials as a single string, like this:

```
"host,user,password,database"
```

Consider exploding this string into parts:

```
$parts = explode(mystring, ',');
```

then feeding the parts into `mysqli_connect`:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($parts[0], $parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[3]);
```

It may not be a great idea to do this, however, since a password may contain the character you're using to split the string.

Answer (score 2):

You passed the string `"'localhost', 'root', '','news_db'"`

You're supposed to pass four strings: `'localhost'`, `'root'`, `''`, and `'news_db'`

So it read `"'localhost', 'root', '','news_db'"` as the first string and now needs the other three strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the connection details in an array and then use splat operator to populate the parameters in `mysqli_connect()`.

```
$credentials = ['localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database'];

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli(...$credentials);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
```

However, I don't see any benefit in doing so, because it doesn't make your code shorter or cleaner.

Another option is to store the connection details in the INI file and let mysqli pick it up from there. Look for `mysqli.default_host`, `mysqli.default_user` and `mysqli.default_pw` in your configuration file. You can then create an instance of mysqli without passing any parameters. If you don't want to store the database name in the configuration file, you can use `select_db()` method to select the database later on.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset
$mysqli->select_db('dbname');
```

#### A better choice: PDO

I would strongly recommend to switch to PDO instead of mysqli. There are many advantages to doing so. One of them is that you can create the instance of PDO with just DSN

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;user=$username;password=$password;dbname=$db;charset=$charset");
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$con_details = 'localhost, root,  , news_db';
$con = mysqli_connect(...explode(', ', $con_details));
```

explode - create from string to array your variable
and ...array() - from array create parameters from your function